# JSGrid unable to perform search

Tags: ajax, jsgrid

Is there anything we must write externally to perform search on a column. from demos i understand that no code is written , please help me out.
I have filtering:true, so that i have search boxes on each col , when i enter text and hit on enter button of keyboard or search icon nothing happens but it calls a REST-ful service which i have written to get data for grid

Following is my code

```
 controller : {
                        loadData : function(filter) {

                        var d = $.Deferred();

                        $.ajax({
                            url : "myurl",

                            dataType : "json",
                            type : 'POST',
                        }).done(function(response) {

                                    // client-side filtering
     $.grep(response, function(project) {

   return project.Name === filter.Name;
                             });
                            d.resolve({
                                data : response.project

                            });




                        });
                        return d.promise();

                                           },

                    },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The first problem is `$.grep` doesn't change the source array, it returns the result of filtering.
2. Also be sure about data in response, since you filter the `response` while resolving deferred with `response.project`. Apply `grep` to the array of items.
3. Another thing is ensure the format of returning data, if `pageLoading` is `false`, the deferred should be resolved with the array of items (not `{ data: [items] }`).

So depending on #2 and #3 the fixed code could be:

```
.done(function(response) {
    var result = $.grep(response, function(project) {
        return project.Name === filter.Name;
    });

    d.resolve(result);
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried using the above code , but when i use d.resolve(result); i am not able to load data .

Comment: whenever i use  d.resolve({ data : response.project });  only im able load data.   i tried alert(result); but its returning me an empty array

Comment: Set `pageLoading:false` in the grid config to make it work.

Comment: Neither it worked. when i tried to print response or filter the output was `[Object object]` but same when i tried to print result it is `[  ] `............. i tried ` pageLoading : false ` and tried to load data again it says  `No Record Found `

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` in `lodaData` method to be sure what's coming from the server. Post the result (maybe truncated) to the comments.

Comment: `{"listException":false,"pageNumber":0,"listMessage":null,"nextPage":fal    s    e,"totalRecords":0,"listSize":3,"listExceptionId":0,
    "project":[{
 "Description":"something else here ...",
  "Name":"Lake side",
 "Id":1,
      },
 
 {
 "Description":"deluxe",
  "Name":"Jet pack",
 "Id":2,
  },
 
 {
 "Description":"Premium packages",
  "Name":"Good Will Suites",
 "Id":3,
 
 }]
 }`

Comment: Then you are right, you need to grep `response.project` so the code should be `var result = $.grep(response.project ...`

Comment: Thanks a ton for support @tabalin ..You helped a lot .. finally this worked .done(function(response) {
   var result = $.grep(response.project, function(item) {    
   return !filter.Name || filter.Name == item.Name;
  });  
  d.resolve({ 
 data:result
  });

Comment: The code in above comment worked for twice but now it showing some weird behavior.  its returning me an empty array on click of search